# Proving the pigeonhole principle in Cutting Planes

Tags: complexity-theory, proof-techniques

Exercise 3 from https://massimolauria.net/courses/2015.ProofComplexity/lecture6.pdf

> Consider the set of inequalities $x_i+x_j\leq1$ for $1\leq i<j\leq n$.
>
> Find a derivation of $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\leq 1$ in $O(n^2)$ length.

If it were just algebra I could just show by contradiction that at most one $x_i$ could be 1 and be done but how does it translate it into cutting planes PS? I guess a similar idea would be by obtaining $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq n-1 -(n-2)x_i$ for all $i$ through addition of $x_i+x_j$ for all $1\leq j\leq n$ but I'm stuck there.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is by induction. Here is the inductive step.

Suppose that we know both of the following inequalities:
$$
x_1 + \cdots + x_m \leq 1 \\
x_2 + \cdots + x_{m+1} \leq 1
$$
Add them to get
$$
x_1 + 2x_2 + \cdots + 2x_m + x_{m+1} \leq 2
$$
Add the axiom $x_1 + x_{m+1} \leq 1$ to get
$$
2x_1 + \cdots + 2x_{m+1} \leq 3
$$
Divide by 2 and round down to get
$$
x_1 + \cdots + x_{m+1} \leq 1
$$
I'll let you fill in the remaining details.

Comment: Thanks. Adding everything up would then prove a refutation for the pigeonhole principle in O(n^3), right?

Comment: The length of a proof is the number of lines in the proof. Make sure to get your definitions right!

Comment: I have another question regarding exercise 4, rank of the derivation. Could you give me a hint on how to divide the variables to reach a logarithmic rank?

Comment: Go from $n$ to $2n$.

Comment: If I add x_1+...+x_n<=1 ... x_n+...+x_2n<=1 and wrap around I get n*sum(2n) <= 2n. How do you push it to 1?

Comment: It seems like you want to ask a completely new question. Even better, I suggest that you take a few hours to think about it. You will never learn anything if whenever you encounter a difficulty, you immediately ask someone for a hint.